# PostgreSQL, MySQL - redundant update/insert/delete optimization

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization, orm

I have a lot of SQL insert/update/delete statements of which some are redundant. For example I might have the following types of redundancy:

1)

```
INSERT INTO "foo" ("id", ...) VALUES (123, ...)
...
DELETE FROM "foo" WHERE "id" = 123
```

2)

```
INSERT INTO "foo" ("id", "col", ...) VALUES (123, 'value', ...)
...
UPDATE "foo" SET "col" = 'other value' WHERE "id" = 123
```

3)

```
UPDATE "foo" SET "col" = 'value' WHERE "id" = 123
...
UPDATE "foo" SET "col" = 'other value' WHERE "id" = 123
```

4)

```
DELETE FROM "foo" WHERE "id" = 123
...
INSERT INTO "foo" ("id",  ...) VALUES (123, ...)
```

I might have forgotten about some other types of redundancies that are out there. Given that:

- There are **no** `SELECT` queries run in between those insert/update/delete statements,
- The statements run in a single transaction,
- The statements are sent to the database in a single API call, parsed by the database and executed together

how much sense does it make to try to remove those redundancies before sending them to the database? In other words, do databases like PostgreSQL, MySQL have mechanisms in place to remove redundant code by themselves before actually running it?

*Important disclaimer:* I'm not in control of the actual SQL code being run. I write a wrapper around an ORM API, that would have to optimize those statements automatically. However this is hard - there are a lot of things to take care of, such as foreign key and unique constraints. Obviously any optimization on the client side would have a positive effect on the database performance. However this is a complex task, and if only analoguous algorithms already run on the database end, I'd rather let them do the job.

**Solution**

I switched to PostgreSQL 9.0, where both `UNIQUE` and `REFERENCES` constraints are deferrable. In case of a database where that holds it's possible to compress an arbitrary sequence of primitive operations on one row to just a single operation (i.e. ...,`DELETE`, `INSERT` -> `UPDATE`). Of course as mentioned in the answer this assumes there are no triggers (which is my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, there will be no optimizations done, the databases will behave exactly as instructed (`INSERT` first then `DELETE`).

`SQL Server` and `Oracle` support `MERGE` command which combines `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, but it is currently supported neither by `PostgreSQL` nor by `MySQL`.

`MySQL` also supports `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which can help in certain cases.

Comment: So in a way relational database is a rather low level tool, it seems to me. Well, good to know.

Comment: Part of your problem is that some of those changes aren't really redundant, especially if you consider things like triggers which might be designed to fire on every row.

Also, merge doesn't really help unless you can rewrite your queries, in which case you could do some optimizations for other databases as well. 

Also, some databases do have internal optimizations for cases like the above, especially if you can do all those changes within a single transaction. One example would be Postgres Heap-Only Tuples features, which will eliminate some of the on-disk overhead in your type of process.